# Что это за Ошибка 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: modx

На сайте http://labeng.ru/ выскочила ошибка. Сайт на MODX. Я просто перенёс все файлы с другого хостинга и поменял логин, пароль, и базу в config.ini.php. В чём может быть проблема? В файле .htaccess удалил строки типа 
    php_value name value 
    php_flag name on|off

Сорержание файла до редактирования. Что здесь может быть лишним?

```
# For full documentation and other suggested options, please see

# http://svn.modxcms.com/docs/display/MODx096/Friendly+URL+Solutions

# including for unexpected logouts in multi-server/cloud environments

# and especially for the first three commented out rules

#php_flag register_globals Off

#AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]

#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Reduce server overhead by enabling output compression if supported.

#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Comment: Создал файл test.html в корне. И на нём тоже ошибка. Это значит, что проблема с .htaccess?

Comment: > В файле .htaccess удалил строки типа php_value name value php_flag name on|off

Именно из-за ошибок в .htaccess, чаще всего и возникает ошибка 500. Попробуйте закомментировать директиву Options. Или изменить Options +FollowSymLinks  на Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

Comment: Там такой нету.

Comment: Добавил первоначальный текст файла. Что там может быть лишним. И ещё, хостинг был русский, сейчас американский. В этом ничего такого нет?

Comment: Если файл вообще удалить, то test.html всё равно не работает.

Comment: Проверьте права на каталоги и скрипты (755). И повторюсь - попробуйте изменить **Options +FollowSymlinks** на **Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch**

Comment: Угадайка? Логи посмотрите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая проблема может быть если mysql работает в строгом режиме. 
Тогда в логе установки (расположенном в директории /core/cache/logs/install.config..log) появляются ошибки вида

```
    INSERT INTO `modx_system_settings` (`key`, `value`, `xtype`, `namespace`, `area`) VALUES ('upload_maxsize', '104857600', 'textfield', 'core', 'system')
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1364
    [2] => Field 'editedon' doesn't have a default value
).
```

Это означает что в таблицу "modx_system_setting" не были записаны необходимые данные и она пустая.

Для решения можно отредактировать файл /etc/mysql/my.cnf так как описано здесь 
http://itif.ru/oshibka-field-xxx-doesnt-have-a-default-value/

Затем надо переустановить modx